# Topology from neighbourhood axioms

Tags: general-topology

Assuming the neighbourhood axioms (from here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Neighbourhoods_definition). How do I show that $T=\{U \subseteq X : x \in X \implies U \subseteq N(x)\}$ is a topology in the sense of the open set definition (on that same paige)?
Its obvious that $\emptyset \in T$ and why the intersection of a finite number of U in T, is in T.

But it eludes me how to show that an arbitrary union of U in T, is in T. If $U_i \in T$ we know $x \in U_i \implies U_i \subseteq N(x)$. So $x \in \cup U_i \implies x \in U_m \: for  \: certain \: m => U_m \in N(x)$ but how does it folow that $\cup U_i \subseteq N(x)$?
I also don't see why $X \in T$?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of $T$ is incorrect. Since $U$ is a subset of $X$, it cannot possible be a **subset** of any $N(x)$: that would make it a set of subsets of $X$. It can, however, be an **element** of an $N(x)$. What you mean is that

$$T=\{U\subseteq X:x\in U\to U\in N(x)\}\;,$$

the collection of sets that are nbhds of each of their elements.

Let $\mathscr{U}\subseteq T$, and let $V=\bigcup\mathscr{U}$; to show that $V\in T$, we must show that if $x\in V$, then there is an $N_x\in N(x)$ such that $N_x\subseteq V$. So suppose that $x\in V$; then there is a $U_x\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $x\in U_x$. And $U_x\in T$, so there is an $N_x\in N(x)$ such that $N_x\subseteq U_x\subseteq V$, which is exactly what we needed to show. It follows that $V\in T$ and hence that $T$ is closed under taking arbitrary unions.

Comment: +1, but: The internet is large, and the abbreviation nbhds is unncessary and sligtly opaque.

Comment: @Thomas: My experience in over two years of using it here is that it is almost always understood. Given my arthritis and the amount of typing that I do, I take that to be sufficient justification for it.

Comment: Oh ofcourse! my bad. The closure under unions is clear now, thanx! But I still don't see why the whole set $X \in T$?
What I wanna show is $x \in X \implies X \in N(x)$, which is the same as (i think)) $\forall x \in X, X \in N(x)$, ie. for every x, X is a neighbourhood of x. Which sounds very reasonable, but how dus it follow from the axioms? I don't see that.

Comment: @Ferdinand: It follows from axiom (4): each point has a nbhd $M_x$ such that that $M_x$ is a nbhd of each point of $M_x$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thought axiom 4 said: $\forall M_x \in N(x),\exists M_x \supseteq N_x \in N(x) \: such \: that \: \forall y \in N_x:N_x \in N(y)$ ie. for ever neighbourhood $M_x$ of x, there is a 'smaller' neighbourhood $N_x$ of x such that $N_x$ is a nbhd of every element in $N_x$.
That's different from what u said? The way I see it, if I start with a nbhd, with axiom (4) I can only get 'smaller' ones, thus never X itself?

Comment: @Ferdinand: What I wrote is an immediate consequence of axiom (4) and the fact that every point has a nbhd. Let $x\in X$; there is some $N_x\in N(x)$, and by (4) there is an $M_x\in N_x$ such that $M_x\subseteq N_x$ and $M_x$ is a nbhd of each of its points (meaning that if $y\in M_x$, then $M_x\in N(y)$). Thus, for each $x\in X$ there is an $M_x\in N(x)$ that is a nbhd of each of points. And that is precisely what is needed for you to conclude that $M_x\in T$.

Comment: First of all, how do you know there is such a $N_x$. As far as I can tell, there is no axiom which says that every point has a nbhd?
Second, you conclude $M_x \in T$, but what I want is $X \in T$ for every x in X right?

Comment: @Ferdinand: No, that’s not what you want. You want to show that $X\in T$. You’ve already shown that $T$ is closed under arbitrary unions, so if each $x$ has a nbhd $M_x\in T$, then on the one hand $\bigcup_{x\in X}M_x\in T$, and on the other hand $\bigcup_{x\in X}M_x=\ldots\;$? // The definition to which you linked specifies that the function **N** assigns to each point of $x$ a **non-empty** collection of nbhds.

Comment: I'll take arthritis as a valid reason :) A lot of people on here seem to abbreviate for less valid reasons. I figured what "nbrhd" meant, but it still caused a hitch in reading - the brain has to stop and rcgnz an unfmlr word.